# (Google docs) bold symbol in equation environment (`through `insert` -> equation`)?

Tags: latex, google-docs

In google docs, when using `insert -> equation` I can not type bold symbol by using latex code (like \mathbf{n}, \boldsymbol{n}). How to do this?

Here, I need solutions when using `insert -> equation`, not solutions in other tools like using addons *Auto-LaTex Equation* or *Docx2LaTeX*